# How to create a ClusterSingleton actor in F#

Tags: f#, akka.net

It is simple to create Akka.NET actors in F# using the functional pattern, like `actorOf2`:

```
let aref = spawn system "my-actor" (actorOf2 myFunction)
```

but there are other actors like the [ClusterSingleton](http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-singleton) that require using an OO approach so I can get the actor by type:

```
type MySingletonActor() =
    inherit UntypedActor()

// then something like
system.ActorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.Props(Props.Create<MySingletonActor>() ... )
```

Is there any way to use the functional pattern from F# to create an actor for use as a ClusterSingleton?